# Timer running status in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, properties, timer

In Windows Forms, How to check whether the timer is running or stopped?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [the Enabled property of the Timer class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx)